# How can I make DIVs within a display: table-cell fill the cell?

Tags: css

I have a problem using the display: table features of CSS. I am getting my basic outline to work but now I would like to make two DIVs fill up the vertical space in a table-cell. Sounds easy but I am not sure how to do this. Here's an example:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
a            a  b  ccccccccccccccccc  b
a            a  b  c               c  b
a            a  b  c               c  b
a            a  b  c               c  b
a            a  b  c               c  b
a            a  b  ccccccccccccccccc  b
a            a  b  dddddddddddddddddd b
a            a  b  d                d b
a            a  b  dddddddddddddddddd b
a            a  b                     b
a            a  b                     b
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

DIV a is a sidebar and coded as a display: table-cell
DIV b is a body area and coded as a display: table-cell

Inside of the body "b" I have two column DIV's with Id's of c and d. What I would like is for the DIV d to stretch to the bottom of the DIV b to fill any remaining space.

Here's the code with inline styles just to make it easy to read:

```
<div>
    <div id="a" style='display: table-cell; background-color: red;'>aaaaaa
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        aaaaaa
    </div>
    <div id="b" style='display: table-cell; background-color: green;'>bbbbbb
        <div id="c" style='background-color: pink;'>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div id="d" style='background-color: yellow;'>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uMSEC/)

Can anyone think of a good way to code this? I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only interested in the visual effect, you might be interested in faux columns: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Here is your example updated to use that technique (images not necessary in this case):

```
<div>
    <div id="a" style='display: table-cell; background-color: red;'>aaaaaa
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        aaaaaa
    </div>
    <div id="b" style='display: table-cell; background-color: yellow;'>
        <span style='background-color: green;'>bbbbbb</span>
        <div id="c" style='background-color: pink;'>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div id="d">
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uMSEC/2/

If you actually want to position content at the end of the column, you can still do it by making b `relative` and positioning another div with absolute at `bottom: 0`.

Comment: Hello, Can you check your example fiddle. I think you gave the wrong URL. Thanks

Comment: @SamanthaJ I've added the HTML in my comment directly, the URL was working for me. In case it wasn't clear from my post, the div d doesn't strectch to the bottom, but for the viewer there is no visual difference.

Comment: One of my big problems is that the DIVs have curved borders. Sorry I should have mentioned this in the post.

Comment: Then I think you'll need to use JS - if that's acceptable, I can write an example.